# Facebook API domain errors documentation

Tags: api, facebook, dns, fbconnect

Anybody knows where I can find documentations of **frustrating domain errors** from facebook API?

Like: error domain 1000, 603, 3, 601, etc..?

I can not find exact explanations what they means. I would help to debug API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of error codes that's returned by Facebook:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes

Answer (score 1):

Don't you love it how no body wants to answer FB Connect questions? I got a 601 and I just NSLogged out the query and found I was passing in a bad uid for something.